# Django admin ManyToManyField filter by type for same table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had Two table name

1. Reservation
2. Services

   In service table i am storing two type of data

   1. Service
   2. Addon Service

**Models.py**

```
class services(models.Model):   
    Service_type_CHOICES = (
     (1, 'Service'),
     (2, 'Addon'),
    )

    service_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Service_type_CHOICES,) 

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Reservation Table

```
class reservations(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField()
    arrival=models.DateTimeField()
    services_id=models.ManyToManyField(services, related_name='services')
    addons_id=models.ManyToManyField(services, related_name='addons')
```

Now in my admin it is showing like below screenshot
[image]

Currently it is showing all the services under both the feilds. i want to filter it by type. how can i achieve this in Django admin.

I want to display service type 1 in first place.
i.e cat1 and cat2

and on addons id i want to show type 2 services only.
i.e Addon1 and Addon2

Comment: Why don't you create a separate `Service` and `Addon` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to`, as specified in the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/

In your case:

```
class reservations(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField()
    arrival=models.DateTimeField()
    services_id=models.ManyToManyField(services, limit_choices_to={'type': 1}, related_name='services')
    addons_id=models.ManyToManyField(services, limit_choices_to={'type': 2}, related_name='addons')
```